# Downloading images and display on table cell (Concurrent)

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

My app displays images in tableView cells What I want to achieve is to load the image in sequence even if the cell has disappeared off the screen. For example, I have cell 1 to 100, the cell is displayed and the images starts to download in background from 1 to 100 even if the user have already scrolled to cell 78. I'd also want to only download one to two image at a time so I don't bog up the network. With these criteria in mind, I was wondering what sort of setup would be most appropriate?

At the moment, I am using AlamoFire to download image. Would a combination of Alamofire with some sort of NSOperationQueue be suitable. I am very un familiar with NSOperationQueue at this stage. So I thought I'd try to find a recommended industry practice before I start going deep into setting NSOperationQueue

I'd also like to combine the functionality to continue the download even when the app is in background

Note. Any alternative library or framework solution is also welcome

Comment: For a suggestion use `SDWebImage` lib it will do exactly you want for your `tableViewCell`.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution out there is `SDWebImage`. The link to this repository is [here](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage).
If you wanna do it your own way without having any dependency then you have to follow the same things that SDWebImage does.

In short,

- Asynchronously start download in thread, which downloads the images from the URL concurrently.
- Then after downloading, use `NSCache`, to store the image and use the
  imageURL as the key.
- After storing the image in `NSCache`, also write the image in `NSCacheDirectory`, with the imagename same as that of its URL.

Now while fetching you have to check, whether the image exists in `NSCache`, using the imageURL as the key you can easily search that. If found, return image or then search `NSCacheDirectory`, whether the image exists there or not. If not then you must download the image and follow the steps once again.

Now `NSCache` is like the RAM. The data stored there will remain there as long as the Application is active. Once terminated, the data in `NSCache` will get cleaned.
Hence we also write the file in `NSCacheDirectory`, as data over here is persistent to as long as the app is not deleted from the device.

I hope I could make you understand as to how this thing works.
Cheers.